# How to show blog posts on product page

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, liquid

I am trying to show blog posts on product pages by matching their tags. I have this code, but the problem is it's fetching only the latest 50 posts. How can I loop through all articles?

```html
{% for article in blogs.news.articles %}
 {% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% if article.tags contains tag %}
  {{ article.title }}
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shopify have a limit of 50 items per loop for collections and blogs. This means that you can't go outside those limitations.

This limitation is set in order to keep the requests to their server as small as possible.

So the short answer is that you can't loop more than 50 articles or products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that there is 50 items limit. However, in Shopify's help section [link](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags), it says that for 50+ results, you are supposed to use paginate tag. I was more looking for an answer on how to iterate in blocks of 50 and thus check all blog posts.

Comment: @AmberHazel, to do that, you'd need a combination of `AJAX` and a new page template that displays your current logic using pagination. Complex but certainly doable..

Comment: @HymnZ Do you maybe know of any Shopify theme that does something similar? Or a guide on that maybe?

Comment: @AmberHazel, refer this - https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/diy-implementing-autocomplete-with-search-144104